# Project '..\someProject.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp2.2'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'

Tags: .net, compiler-errors, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8, target-framework

I am trying to `build a project` with below `versions` -

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In this project, there is a `reference project` which also `targets the same version`.

When I try to `build` the `project` I get the below `error` -

[image]

Please help me to resolve this.

**Observation** - When I try to `build` these `projects` separately for `both 4.8 and 5.0` they compile without `errors`.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are referencing a library with a different .net version. Try finding another (version of the) library that uses .netframework 4.8

Answer (score 0):

.net core version 2.2 is not compatible with .net framework 4.8.

You can low you project to .net core 2.1 that is stil compatible.